# Progress bar not updating from background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

What I'm trying to do is to have a progress bar as a separate window that will update based on the progress of other long processing work on another form. When I debug through the progress bar code, DoWork and ProgressChanged are both called as expected but the UI fails to update. The code even reaches the Worker_RunWorkerCompleted and closes the progressbar. I've read about 20 articles and can't nail down the issue. I know that I should be using a view model for WPF but the code below is simplified to see if I can just get the progress bar to update. I know I'm missing something simple but I can't put my finger on what it is.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CGXAcquisition.Forms.Dialog.FileProgressBar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="File Upload Progress" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class FileProgressBar : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        private int fileLines = 0;
        private int totalFileLines = 0;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public int FileLines
        {
            get { return fileLines; }
            set 
            { 
                fileLines = value;
                Percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)fileLines / TotalFileLines);
                OnPropertyChanged("FileLines");
            }
        }
        public int TotalFileLines
        {
            get { return totalFileLines; }
            set { totalFileLines = value; }
        }
        public int Percentage { get; set; }

        public FileProgressBar(int totalLines)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TotalFileLines = totalLines;
            Loaded += Window_ContentRendered;
        }
        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                int percent = i / 100;
                worker.ReportProgress(percent, i);
            }
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

    }
```

The code that creates the progress bar which exists on another form:

```
private void ShowProgressBar()
        {
            progress = new FileProgressBar(FileInfo.LineCount);
            progress.Show();
        }
```

I call ShowProgressBar() in my OnLoaded event

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowProgressBar();
        }
```

and in my constructor I add the event handler to the Loaded event

```
Loaded += OnLoaded;
```

I expected to see the UI update with the code I have. I've tried using a Dispatcher to update the UI but as far as I understand it, the worker_ProgressChanged should alleviate the need for a dispatcher. I've looked through StackOverflow, MSDN and several other blogs and nothing has helped me identify what I'm missing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**
I finally noticed that my math was wrong. This line
int percent = i / 100;
Should be
int percent ((int)(double)i / 100 * 100);

I know that I could have just used i but I wanted to do it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Backgroundworker` is a deprecated API. Instead you should use `Task.Run` or asynchronous APIs where possible. To report progress you should use the `Progress<T>` class.

The main issue with your code: your calculations are wrong. Currently, the max value that your formula produces is `1` (`100/100`).
Furthermore, the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` accepts an `int` as percentage argument. The implicit type cast from `double` to `int` will truncate the decimal places of the `double` value. Hence, `0.9d` becomes `0`.
This means the `ProgressBar.Value` will be `0` the whole time until `i == 100`. Then the value will be `1` and you close the `Window`.

The correct formula to calculate percentage is: `value / max_value * 100`.
It is also important to understand that because of the division your participating numeric variables or the divisor must be of type `double`. Otherwise the intermediate result value will be truncated due to the implicit conversion from `double` to `int`. In other words you completely lose the decimal places (no rounding).

You don't tell any details about your background job. But from the window's name I assume you read from a file. In this case don't execute the job on a background thread. Instead use the asynchronous API of the `StreamReader`.

Additionally, controls never implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It has several downsides: performance, property can't serve as binding target, can't be animated etc.
Instead controls, or types that extend `DependencyObject` in general, should implement their properties as dependency properties.

Your improved implementation of `FileProgressBar` and fixed calculations should look as follows:

**FileProgressBar.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class FileProgressBar : Window
{
  public int FileLines
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(FileLinesProperty);
    set => SetValue(FileLinesProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FileLinesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FileLines",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(FileProgressBar),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnFileLinesChanegd));

  // If this property is used for data binding it must be a dependency property too
  public int TotalFileLines { get; set; }

  // If this property is used for data binding it must be a dependency property too
  public int Percentage { get; set; }

  public FileProgressBar(int totalLines)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.TotalFileLines = totalLines;
    this.Loaded += Window_ContentRendered;
  }

  private static void OnFileLinesChanegd(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var this_ = d as FileProgressBar;
    this_.Percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)e.NewValue / this_.TotalFileLines * 100d);
  }

  private async void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var progressReporter = new Progress<double>(progress => pbStatus.Value = progress);
    await DoWorkAsync(progressReporter);
    OnWorkCompleted();
  }

  private void OnWorkCompleted() => Close();

  async Task DoWorkAsync(IProgress<double> progressReporter)
    => await Task.Run(async () => await LongRunningTaskAsync(progressReporter));

  private static async Task LongRunningTaskAsync(IProgress<double> progressReporter)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
      double percent = i / 100d * 100d;
      progressReporter.Report(percent);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the insight on BackgroundWorker vs Task. Great answer.